# System that does not work

Tags: raspberry-pi, induction-motor, solid-state-relay

[image]

Hello, i build a system which suppose to run speed control of electric engine, with loginc of Raspberry Pi.

Control Signal does not go through SSR.

## System Connection Logic:

(1) RaspberryPi 3 ->

(2) Bi-Directional Logic Level Converter Hookup Guide ->

https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide
to change 3V3 logic to 5V logic

(3) SSR-40 DA ->

[https://www.amazon.com/SSR-40DA-Solid-Output-24-380V-SSR-40/dp/B07FVHWN82](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07FVHWN82)
to change input signals from DC to 230 V with optocoupler, zerophase and triac

(4) PSC Engine, 1phase, 0,35 A, 1,5 mF

[image]
Electronic circuit schematics of SSR, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLP_L7Mgz6M - Solid State Relay || DIY or Buy,

## Problem description:

Engine speed control is being build.
At the beginning i though that SSR itself, will be sufficient solution, to command signal ON/OFF, between computer and motor.

It didn't worked. DC signal from 3V3 GPIO, can not open signal on AC side, and Raspberry do not have 5V control system.

**However!**

1. While using SSR: 
   I can run engine, if i connect DC side of SSR to constant 5V pin. 
   (if i connect DC side of SSR to constant 3V3 pin it DOES NOT work).
2. While using SSR: 
   **Yes I can control speed control when using mechanical relay** like JQC3F-5VDC-C between Raspberry and SSR, where 3V3 signal opens logic, and 5V is let through to SSR.

(But i do not want to use this solution - mechanical relay wont last long with such a frequent work)

3. To have other device in the middle, instead of Relay, I bought (2) Bi-Directional Logic to let 5V goes, but it does not move the engine.
4. I connect (2) Bi-Directional device to control Mechanical relay, (to check if (2) works), it is proven that (2) works

## What i need to know:

So far as,

- SSR with 3V3 signal directly Raspberry Logic AND
- SSR with 5V signal indirectly through (2) Bi-Directional

do not let me the 230 V through,

But

- 5V Signal indirectly through Relay
  does let me to control the speed

**what i suppose to change in the system to make it work**,
Is there any resistor i suppose to put in series somewhere in the system, or what?

Thank you!

Comment: They have a datasheet at the Fotek site:  [LINK](http://www.fotek.com.hk/solid/SSR-1.htm)  Looks like they list the trigger current as 7.5 mA @ 12V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supplying enough current to the SSR to turn it on.

According to the [datasheet](http://www.fotek.com.hk/solid/SSR-1.htm) the trigger uses 7.5 mA @ 12 V.

5V is probably enough, but your level shifter does not allow enough current.

You can probably get this to work with just a logic-level MOSFET and 5 V:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS7mRt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: That works, actually I did it shortly after the original question was published. I used 2N2222 Transistor with 220 Ohm resistor at the gate, and logic works, thanks!